# List of all existing WordPress plugins

Tags: plugins

Is there a place from where I can get a list of all existing WordPress plugins, located in http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

I am trying to test my website for vulnerabilities and need such list.
Thanks

Comment: For anyone (like me) just searching the plain number, the list contains 68616 items.

Comment: hi Simon - many thanks for your help. How did you find this number!? Look forward to hear from you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/

Good luck. It's a very long list and Otto normally becomes very angry if someone try to scrape the complete SVN-Repo.

Comment: What? How is Otto?

Comment: Hmm - who is Otto?

Answer (score 1):

#### SVN

You find a list of all plugins inside the SVN - https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/

#### Git

Another option is the mirror on GitHub, there have a more useful API to doing thinks with the list. - https://github.com/wp-plugins

#### API

Also, you can use the API and his functions to get a more usable solution to parse for changes, etc., see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_api/

#### Additional

An additional service is https://wpdirectory.net/ which gives you also lot of helpful functions. WP Dir is a web service there allowing lightning fast regex searches of the WordPress Plugin/Theme Directories. Especially the regex is really helpful.

Comment: thank you for the hints. Thanks especially for the link to the wp-directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer but I tried to solve my own problem the best way I could.

## Getting a list of plugins

This will **not** return ALL plugins but it will return the **top rated** ones:

```
$plugins = plugins_api('query_plugins', array(
    'per_page' => 100,
    'browse' => 'top-rated',
    'fields' =>
        array(
            'short_description' => false,
            'description' => false,
            'sections' => false,
            'tested' => false,
            'requires' => false,
            'rating' => false,
            'ratings' => false,
            'downloaded' => false,
            'downloadlink' => false,
            'last_updated' => false,
            'added' => false,
            'tags' => false,
            'compatibility' => false,
            'homepage' => false,
            'versions' => false,
            'donate_link' => false,
            'reviews' => false,
            'banners' => false,
            'icons' => false,
            'active_installs' => false,
            'group' => false,
            'contributors' => false
        )));
```

## Save the data as JSON

Since the data that we get is huge and it will be bad for performance, we try to get the `name` and the `slug` out of the array and then we write it in a JSON file:

```
$plugins_json = '{' . PHP_EOL;
// Get only the name and the slug
foreach ($plugins as $plugin) {
    foreach ($plugin as $key => $p) {
        if ($p->name != null) {
            // Let's beautify the JSON
            $plugins_json .= '  "'. $p->name . '": {' . PHP_EOL;
            $plugins_json .= '      "slug": "' . $p->slug . '"' . PHP_EOL;
            end($plugin);
            $plugins_json .= ($key !== key($plugin)) ? '    },' . PHP_EOL : '   }' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
$plugins_json .= '}';
file_put_contents('plugins.json', $plugins_json);
```

Now we have a slim JSON file with only the data that we need.

To keep updating the JSON file, we run that script to create a JSON file every 24 hours by setting up a Cron Job.