# Get a list of all WordPress.org Plugins?

Tags: plugins, api, wordpress.org

I'm looking for a way to get the list of all plugins listed in the [WordPress.org Plugin Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/).

There is one other post I've [found on StackOverflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95836/list-of-all-existing-wordpress-plugins) regarding this which recommends [using the subversion repository.](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/)

I'd like to do something that organizes them by number of downloads.

I think this is probably possible using the WordPress.org API, but I'm not positive. My attempts thus far have failed. Any ideas?

Comment: close voted as this is not related to wordpress development. If you have questions about wordpress.org you should simply ask the people maintaining it.

Comment: This is related to WordPress development, the WordPress.org Plugin Directory is integrated into WordPress core via the Plugins API.

Comment: Can you post code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 7):

You can start with something like this:

```
https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=query_plugins&request[page]=1&request[per_page]=400
```

I think it's self-explanatory.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing some code or results it is difficult to advise beyond linking you to other tutorials on the web. A quick Google revealed these:

- https://dd32.id.au/projects/wordpressorg-plugin-information-api-docs/
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/communicating-with-the-wordpressorg-plugin-api--wp-33069

As with a lot of the WP codex the official documentation is a little lacking.

Answer (score 0):

good day dear Davemackey - hello Michael Field
its been a long time that this has been asked - but anyway.. here my little idea that i can come up with..

Not the best answer but I tried to solve my own problem the best way I could.

## Getting a list of plugins

This will **not** return ALL plugins but it will return the **top rated** ones:

```
$plugins = plugins_api('query_plugins', array(
    'per_page' => 100,
    'browse' => 'top-rated',
    'fields' =>
        array(
            'short_description' => false,
            'description' => false,
            'sections' => false,
            'tested' => false,
            'requires' => false,
            'rating' => false,
            'ratings' => false,
            'downloaded' => false,
            'downloadlink' => false,
            'last_updated' => false,
            'added' => false,
            'tags' => false,
            'compatibility' => false,
            'homepage' => false,
            'versions' => false,
            'donate_link' => false,
            'reviews' => false,
            'banners' => false,
            'icons' => false,
            'active_installs' => false,
            'group' => false,
            'contributors' => false
        )));
```

## Save the data as JSON

Since the data that we get is huge and it will be bad for performance, we try to get the `name` and the `slug` out of the array and then we write it in a JSON file:

```
$plugins_json = '{' . PHP_EOL;
// Get only the name and the slug
foreach ($plugins as $plugin) {
    foreach ($plugin as $key => $p) {
        if ($p->name != null) {
            // Let's beautify the JSON
            $plugins_json .= '  "'. $p->name . '": {' . PHP_EOL;
            $plugins_json .= '      "slug": "' . $p->slug . '"' . PHP_EOL;
            end($plugin);
            $plugins_json .= ($key !== key($plugin)) ? '    },' . PHP_EOL : '   }' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
$plugins_json .= '}';
file_put_contents('plugins.json', $plugins_json);
```

Now we have a slim JSON file with only the data that we need.

To keep updating the JSON file, we run that script to create a JSON file every 24 hours by setting up a Cron Job.